# Django how to do validate method for the same user to not exist again?

Tags: python, django, validation, django-models, django-rest-framework

this is my code

models.py

```py
class UserAttributes(models.Model):
    airport = models.ForeignKey('airport.Airport', related_name='user_attributes_airport', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    location = PointField(blank=True, null=True)
    user =  models.ForeignKey(
        'users.AerosimpleUser', related_name='user_attributes',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

views.py

```py
class LocationViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    serializer_class=LocationRetrieveSerializer
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'patch', 'put']

    def get_permissions(self):
            switcher = {
                'create': [IsAuthenticated],
                'list': [IsAuthenticated],
                'retrieve': [IsAuthenticated],
                'update': [IsAuthenticated],
                'partial_update': [IsAuthenticated],
            }
            self.permission_classes = switcher.get(self.action, [IsAdminUser])
            return super(self.__class__, self).get_permissions()
    def get_queryset(self):
        return UserAttributes.objects.filter(
            airport__id=self.request.user.aerosimple_user.airport_id).order_by('pk')
```

serializers.py

```py
class LocationRetrieveSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = UserAttributes
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        if UserAttributes.objects.filter(user=self.context["request"].user).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("User Already exists.")
        if UserAttributes.objects.filter(airport=self.context['request'].user.aerosimple_user.airport).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Airport Already exists.")
        user_attributes = UserAttributes.objects.create(**validated_data)
        return user_attributes
```

while trying this i am getting the following error

```
Cannot query "8f21af88-c78e-493e-b40c-a874573a2207": Must be "AerosimpleUser" instance.
```

Comment: Can you please provide at what line that exception was raised on?
The models may be helpful too.

Comment: this is my models.py file
class UserAttributes(models.Model):
    airport = models.ForeignKey('airport.Airport', related_name='user_attributes_airport', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    location = PointField(blank=True, null=True)
    user =  models.ForeignKey(
        'users.AerosimpleUser', related_name='user_attributes',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

Comment: i got the error here in serializers.py


   

 def create(self, validated_data):

        logger.info(self.context["request"].user)

        if UserAttributes.objects.filter(user=self.context["request"].user).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("User Already exists.")
        if UserAttributes.objects.filter(airport=self.context['request'].user.aerosimple_user.airport).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Airport Already exists.")
        user_attributes = UserAttributes.objects.create(**validated_data)
        return user_attributes

Comment: @lohit since you want there to be only one user for user attributes and vice-versa you want a [One-to-one relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/#one-to-one-relationships) for which you should use a [`OneToOneField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield)